# Deployment Issue with GitHub Project

Tags: node.js

I am reaching out for help to resolve an issue I am facing with my GitHub project: https://github.com/rastmob/openai-grammar-correction. I was able to implement the project locally on my computer after some difficulties. Now, I want to deploy it on a Debian 11 server to access it from anywhere.

I was able to access the application using the command "sudo ng serve --host 212.227.31.123 --port 80", but when I make a request, I get an error in the console: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4011/correction' from origin 'http://212.227.31.123' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local."

I would like to know if there is a parameter that needs to be modified in the code for the project to work with the public IP address of my server. Thank you in advance for your help.

I cannot provide a translation into "anfalsi" as it is not a language that exists. If you can provide me with the name of the language, I will be happy to translate the text for you.

Here are some details to better understand the issue[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoxEY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to

```
 http://localhost:4011/correction
```

To run the application in your browser try going to

```
 http://212.227.31.123:4011/correction
```

Comment: I successfully accessed the application using my IP address http://212.227.31.123:80, but I received an error message when I tried to launch the request to correct the text."

Comment: @gabrielbellec -- there is no way to help you if you don't show us the source code.   All I can say given that is it, it sounds like you have a bug.

Comment: I can give you the code with pleasure. Which file do you want to see in order to understand?

Comment: @gabrielbellec -- I can't answer that.  You have not told us what the error is.  Does the error occur in a particular file?  This kind of information would be helpful.  Please put in some effort.